# Passing data from form to controller Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying register users in a laravel 5 application using the restful controller.

The problem is that when I dump the data in my store function, I only get the csrf token, but not the values.

Here's what I tried so far:

- `Input::all();`
- `Request::get();`

Here's the code I'm executing:

**Form**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/users">

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">
        Name
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" value="a">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">
        Email
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="a@a.Fr">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="col-lg-2 control-label">
        Pw
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>

    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::only('name','email','password');            
    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $input['name'];
    $user->email = $input['email'];
    $user->password = Hash::make($input['password']);
    $user->save();
}
```

And **Route** is just

```
Route::resource('users','UsersController');
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your input fields are all missing a `name` attribute! For example

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="a">
<!--                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^        -->
```

Comment: Been coding for 10 years and I forgot that as well ha ha ha ;)

Comment: Just came to this post and had exactly the same problem -_-

Comment: oopsie... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should put `name` attributes on the input fields, because html forms communicate with php with `name` attribute.

Example:

```
<input........... name="etc">
```

and in controller use the `name` you have given an input as a key :

```
 $user->name = $input['etc'];
```

```html
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="a">
```